# Blazor Server App on Azure Large number of messages

Tags: azure, blazor, signalr, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I have a Blazor Server page built in.Net8 using server-side prerendering.
The page has a simple input in a component and then it shows a list of 926 objects via a for loop. I know not the best way of doing it and I'm looking to improve it.

The objects in the list are fetched via a single call to an API on afterInitilasiedAsync. The text input is used to live filter the list (which is now in server memory not by API calls)

This simple page is hosted on Azure App service connected to a SignalR service.
When this page is loaded a complete list of SignalR metrics show 900+ SignalR messages in the message count. I then get 50 or so when filtering, and when the filter is cleared another 900+

Is this the expected behavior? This seems very high to me.

I've tried using the browser tools to look at the WS socket messages. I can see a single request which when open shows about 27 messages. Every few seconds I then get two blank messages. (I assume keeping the connection alive).

Well having done some digging if I simple host the Blazor server app in Azure App Service and do not connect it to an additonal SignalR service I'm no longer limited to a certain number of messages but just total bandwidth. So that seems like the better options

Comment: could please tell what you are looking for?

Comment: When this page is loaded, and has rendered the complete list of objects. The SignalR metrics show 900+ SignalR messages in the data out count. 

I then get 50 messages or so when filtering, and when the filter is cleared another 900+

Is this the expected behavior? This seems very high to me.